# Displaying navigation to the right of the drawer/sidebar

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I am making a website (pet project) for myself and I want navigation to take place in a certain area, and not on the entire page. I understand how to do this with React, but not on Flutter, since I have never done web development with it.  For navigation, I use the go_router package version 6.3.

I understand that you can do something like the following, but I don't know how to do it with go_router (no ideas :C)

```
Scaffold(
  body: Row(
    children: [
      MenuWidget(),
      Expanded(child: Navigator()),
    ]
  ),
);
```

GoRouter:

```
final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      pageBuilder: (context, state) =>
          _buildCustomTransitionPage(const Info()),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/empire',
      pageBuilder: (context, state) =>
          _buildCustomTransitionPage(const Empire()),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/chaos',
      pageBuilder: (context, state) =>
          _buildCustomTransitionPage(const Chaos()),
    ),
```

Screen, what I want to do to do:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using ShellRoute (link to documentation [enter link description here](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/go_router/ShellRoute-class.html))
and the following code as a skeleton:

```
return Row(
  children: [
    Menu(),
    Expanded(child: child),
])
```

where the child inside Expanded is what the ShellRoute accepts

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is the example of the above solution

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Main());
}

class Main extends StatelessWidget {
  Main({super.key});
  final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
    initialLocation: '/',
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    routes: <RouteBase>[
      ShellRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state, Widget child) {
          return ShellBody(child: child);
        },
        routes: <RouteBase>[
          GoRoute(
            path: '/',
            pageBuilder: (_, __) => const NoTransitionPage<void>(
              child: Center(
                child: Text('/ body'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: '/shell1',
            pageBuilder: (_, __) => const NoTransitionPage<void>(
              child: Center(
                child: Text('shell1 body'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      routerConfig: _router,
    );
  }
}

class ShellBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const ShellBody({
    required this.child,
    super.key,
  });
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(children: [
      const Menu(),
      Expanded(child: child),
    ]);
  }
}

class Menu extends StatelessWidget {
  const Menu({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: double.infinity,
      width: 300.0,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              GoRouter.of(context).push('/');
            },
            child: const Text('push the same shell route /'),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              GoRouter.of(context).push('/shell1');
            },
            child: const Text('push the same shell route /shell1'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]